# How to split json object extracted from mongodb using java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, split

I have stored some JSON objects in MongoDB collections and using Mongo jar and Java I did full text search, and I am extracting one of my DB fields using below code:

```
String tags2=dbo.getString("Tags");
```

Result:

```
[["pdf","java","c++"]["perl","pdf","c"]["java","c++"]]
```

My requirement is to split all the words and remove duplicates. I require the following output:

```
pdf
java
c++
c
perl
```

Can you please suggest a way to get this?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Are there definitely no commas between the sub-arrays?

Comment: I don't know what your schema looks like, but `distinct` may be a reasonable option. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this in GSON

```
JsonArray finalResult = null;
JsonParser  parser = new JsonParser();
String tags2=dbo.getString("Tags");
JsonElement elem   = parser.parse(tags2);
finalResult = elem.getAsJsonArray();
for(int i=o;i<finalResult .size();i++)
{
//Get individual array and get the fields as String and store it anywhere
}
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply,but do i need to import any gson jars, because i am getting error at "elem"

Comment: The above code will not compile because `elem` has not been initialized yet. And yes you will need the GSON jar on your classpath

Comment: its working but i need to write this code in another for loop      for( Iterator <Object> it = results2.iterator();it.hasNext();), so when i kept this code, for every iteration i am getting result, how can i get the tags for all results in a single string or json variable

Answer (score 1):

As your JSON is invalid, you could parse your output using a regex pattern to extract the values. These can then be added to a `Set` in order to remove duplicates, e.g.:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(tags2);

final Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    unique.add(m.group());
}

assert unique == ["perl", "java", "c", "c++", "pdf"];
```

You may need to use a different `Set` implementation if some kind of ordering is important to you.

Alternatively, if your JSON is valid you can simply do:

```
final String[][] result = new Gson().fromJson(tags2, String[][].class);
```

And then add the contents of `result` to a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

Various libraries such as [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) will help you to do that.

Example for ints:

```
int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]", int[].class);
```

Your example is solved by:

```
String tags2 = "[[\"pdf\",\"java\",\"c++\"],[\"perl\",\"pdf\",\"c\"],[\"java\",\"c++\"]]"; 
// added commas between the arrays to make sure the JSON is valid
// your code: String tags2=dbo.getString("Tags");
Set<String> elems = new HashSet<String>();
JsonElement rootJSonElement  = new JsonParser().parse(tags2);
for (JsonElement jsonElement : rootJSonElement.getAsJsonArray()) {
    for (JsonElement innerJsonElement : jsonElement.getAsJsonArray()) {
        elems.add(innerJsonElement.getAsString());
    } 
}
System.out.println(elems);
```