# How to add all results to a string in for loop using java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, unique

i am getting following output

```
for( Iterator <Object> it = results2.iterator();it.hasNext();)
            {
                BasicDBObject result  = (BasicDBObject) it.next();
                BasicDBObject dbo = (BasicDBObject) result.get("obj");
                String title2=(String) dbo.getString("Filename");
                        system.out.println("filename"+title2);
                 JsonArray finalResult = null;
                 JsonParser  parser = new JsonParser();
                 String tags2=dbo.getString("Tags");
                 JsonElement elem   = parser.parse(tags2);

                 finalResult = elem.getAsJsonArray();
                 for(int i=0;i<finalResult .size();i++)
                 {
                    JsonElement keys=finalResult.get(i);
                    System.out.println("final Result:"+keys);

                 }
}
```

Output:

```
filename:sample.pdf
finalresult:"java"
            "pdf"
            "c++"

filename:sample1.pdf
finalresult:"java1"
            "pdf"
            "c+"
```

But i want to get the overall tags for all the files by removing duplicates

```
filename:sample.pdf
filename:sample1.pdf
finalresult:"java"
            "pdf"
            "c++"
            "java1"
            "c+"
```

my tag field in mondodb is

```
["java","php","c++]
```

can you please suggest me how to do this

thanks

Comment: you should get familiar \with Sets

Comment: Use a java Set, here is an example.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490178/how-to-use-java-set

Comment: If the result is not too large, you can simply call the method toArray on the DBCursor to get an array. Then, loop trough the array the first time to print the file name and the second time to print the tags. And if you want each tag to be printed only once, you should use set as suggested by okram123.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split json object extracted from mongodb using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613994/how-to-split-json-object-extracted-from-mongodb-using-java)

Comment: Do you really need to use GSON to parse that value?  Are the tags stored as an array in MongoDB, or are they really stored as a String?